# Error running gitlab-ci.yml script under Alpine Docker based Image

Tags: docker, gitlab, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So, I need to run ssh when running deploy job using Gitlab CI. I use `https://hub.docker.com/r/nmfzone/ssh-client-light/` docker image.

But, I can't. Because this error was thrown.

```
Checking out 32af65e1 as development...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Unknown cipher type 'if [ -x /usr/local/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/bash ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/bash 
elif [ -x /bin/bash ]; then
    exec /bin/bash 
elif [ -x /usr/local/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/local/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /usr/bin/sh ]; then
    exec /usr/bin/sh 
elif [ -x /bin/sh ]; then
    exec /bin/sh 
else
    echo shell not found
    exit 1
fi
```

How do I fix it?

I used this config in Dockerfile when building `https://hub.docker.com/r/nmfzone/ssh-client-light/` image.

```
FROM gliderlabs/alpine:3.4

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --update bash && \
    apk add openssh-client

# Security fix for CVE-2016-0777 and CVE-2016-0778
RUN echo -e 'Host *\nUseRoaming no' >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

ENTRYPOINT ["ssh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use gitlab's ssh executor or change your docker's entrypoint to a proper shell and run ssh inside your script. Gitlab's docker runner does't support entry-point which are not a shell.

Comment: Thanks. You're correct. I forgot to set entry point on my Dockerfile. `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who has this issue as well, you need something like this in your Dockerfile if you have installed bash shell.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```